# Mahout installation

Tags: mahout

This is the error i get when doing mvn clean install in trunk directory. Some tests are failing and core is not being installed. Any suggestions as to what can go wrong?
I have installed maven and I know it has installed correctly because mvn --version works.

Here is the whole output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.mahout:mahout-integration:jar:0.7-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: ${project.groupId}:mahout-core:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 121, column 17
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Mahout
[INFO] Mahout Build Tools
[INFO] Mahout Math
[INFO] Mahout Core
[INFO] Mahout Integration
[INFO] Mahout Examples
[INFO] Mahout Release Package
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Mahout 0.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mahout ---
[INFO] Deleting /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:process (default) @ mahout ---
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ mahout ---
[INFO] Installing /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/mahout/mahout/0.7-SNAPSHOT/mahout-0.7-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mahout Build Tools 0.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mahout-buildtools ---
[INFO] Deleting /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/buildtools/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ mahout-buildtools ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ mahout-buildtools ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ mahout-buildtools ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/buildtools/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mahout-buildtools ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) @ mahout-buildtools ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/buildtools/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ mahout-buildtools ---
[INFO] Building jar: /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/buildtools/target/mahout-buildtools-0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ mahout-buildtools ---
[INFO] Installing /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/buildtools/target/mahout-buildtools-0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/mahout/mahout-buildtools/0.7-SNAPSHOT/mahout-buildtools-0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/buildtools/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/mahout/mahout-buildtools/0.7-SNAPSHOT/mahout-buildtools-0.7-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mahout Math 0.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Deleting /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- mahout-collection-codegen-plugin:1.0:generate (default) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Writing to /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/generated-sources/org/apache
[INFO]
```

.....

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Compiling 347 source files to /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Compiling 118 source files to /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.apache.mahout.math.als.AlternatingLeastSquaresSolverTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.803 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestSparseMatrix
Tests run: 57, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.19 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.decomposer.hebbian.TestHebbianSolver
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.991 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.decomposer.lanczos.TestLanczosSolver
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.078 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.PivotedMatrixTest
Tests run: 58, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.287 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestDenseVector
Tests run: 39, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestSparseColumnMatrix
Tests run: 57, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestDenseMatrix
Tests run: 57, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.list.ShortArrayListTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.list.ByteArrayListTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.419 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.list.LongArrayListTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.list.IntArrayListTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.list.CharArrayListTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.list.FloatArrayListTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.list.DoubleArrayListTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.VectorTest
Tests run: 20, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.009 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.stats.OnlineSummarizerTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.055 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.stats.OnlineExponentialAverageTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.stats.LogLikelihoodTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.QRDecompositionTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.041 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestSingularValueDecomposition
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestSparseRowMatrix
Tests run: 57, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestOrderedIntDoubleMapping
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestRandomAccessSparseVector
Tests run: 39, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.solver.TestConjugateGradientSolver
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.solver.LSMRTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.solver.EigenDecompositionTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.155 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.jet.random.engine.MersenneTwisterTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.jet.random.GammaTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.589 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.jet.random.ExponentialTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.832 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.jet.random.NegativeBinomialTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.074 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.jet.random.NormalTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.267 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.jet.stat.ProbabilityTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.jet.stat.GammaTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.128 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.PermutedVectorViewTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestVectorView
Tests run: 35, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.032 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenByteShortHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenCharFloatHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenShortShortHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenDoubleShortHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenFloatLongHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntFloatHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenShortObjectHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenObjectIntHashMapTest
Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.05 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenFloatCharHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenDoubleByteHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenByteFloatHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntObjectHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntIntHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenDoubleObjectHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenDoubleDoubleHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenByteByteHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenCharCharHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenFloatByteHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenShortDoubleHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntDoubleHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenCharDoubleHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenDoubleIntHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.113 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenShortLongHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenByteIntHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenObjectDoubleHashMapTest
Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongShortHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntByteHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenCharShortHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenObjectShortHashMapTest
Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongFloatHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongLongHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenDoubleFloatHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenCharObjectHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenObjectFloatHashMapTest
Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenShortFloatHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenByteCharHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.124 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenDoubleCharHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenFloatShortHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntLongHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenShortIntHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenShortByteHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntShortHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenObjectCharHashMapTest
Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenByteDoubleHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenObjectLongHashMapTest
Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenByteLongHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenByteObjectHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenShortCharHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongObjectHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenFloatFloatHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenCharLongHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongIntHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.019 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongDoubleHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenDoubleLongHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenFloatObjectHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongByteHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenFloatIntHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenFloatDoubleHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenCharByteHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenIntCharHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenCharIntHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenLongCharHashMapTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.map.OpenObjectByteHashMapTest
Tests run: 19, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.MurmurHashTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.008 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.MurmurHash3Test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.CholeskyDecompositionTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.944 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestSequentialAccessSparseVector
Tests run: 39, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.032 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.set.OpenDoubleHashSetTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.set.OpenShortHashSetTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.set.OpenIntHashSetTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.set.OpenCharHashSetTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.set.OpenFloatHashSetTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.set.OpenLongHashSetTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.set.OpenByteHashSetTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.TestMatrixView
Tests run: 48, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.051 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.ssvd.SequentialBigSvdTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.019 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.common.RandomUtilsTest
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1867, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Building jar: /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:test-jar (default) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Building jar: /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-source-plugin:2.1.2:jar-no-fork (attach-sources) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] org already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math/list already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math/function already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math/map already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math/set already added, skipping
[INFO] Building jar: /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO] org already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math/list already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math/function already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math/map already added, skipping
[INFO] org/apache/mahout/math/set already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ mahout-math ---
[INFO] Installing /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/mahout/mahout-math/0.7-SNAPSHOT/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/mahout/mahout-math/0.7-SNAPSHOT/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/mahout/mahout-math/0.7-SNAPSHOT/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] Installing /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/math/target/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar to /root/.m2/repository/org/apache/mahout/mahout-math/0.7-SNAPSHOT/mahout-math-0.7-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Mahout Core 0.7-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ mahout-core ---
[INFO] Deleting /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/core/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ mahout-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ mahout-core ---
[INFO] Compiling 645 source files to /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/core/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (default) @ mahout-core ---
[WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/core/target/classes
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ mahout-core ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mahout-core ---
[INFO] Compiling 228 source files to /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/core/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) @ mahout-core ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /opt/ibm/biginsights/trunk/core/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.als.ParallelALSFactorizationJobTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 43.663 sec
```

...

```
Running org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.LocalSSVDPCADenseTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.226 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.LocalSSVDSolverDenseTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 49.06 sec
Running org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.LocalSSVDSolverSparseSequentialTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.181 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.SSVDCommonTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 sec
```

...
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
    Running org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.VisualizerTest
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.012 sec <<< FAILURE!
    Running org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.data.DataTest
    Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.184 sec
...
    Running org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.FPGrowthSyntheticDataTest
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 126.143 sec
    Running org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.PFPGrowthTest
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 11.852 sec <<< FAILURE!
    Running org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.PFPGrowthRetailDataTest
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 14.917 sec <<< FAILURE!
    Running org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.fpgrowth.FrequentPatternMaxHeapTest
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.088 sec
...
    Results :

```
Failed tests: 
  testTreeVisualize(org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.VisualizerTest): expected:<
  testForestVisualize(org.apache.mahout.classifier.df.tools.VisualizerTest): expected:<Tree[1]:

Tests in error: 
  runPCATest1(org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.LocalSSVDPCADenseTest): Bt job unsuccessful.
  testSSVDSolverPowerIterations1(org.apache.mahout.math.hadoop.stochasticsvd.LocalSSVDSolverSparseSequentialTest): Bt job unsuccessful.
  testStartParallelFPGrowth(org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.PFPGrowthTest): Job failed!
  testStartParallelFPGrowthInSteps(org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.PFPGrowthTest): Job failed!
  testRetailDataMinSup100(org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.PFPGrowthRetailDataTest): Job failed!
  testRetailDataMinSup100InSteps(org.apache.mahout.fpm.pfpgrowth.PFPGrowthRetailDataTest): Job failed!

Tests run: 674, Failures: 2, Errors: 6, Skipped: 1
```

Comment: Change the title of the question, please:)

Answer (score 1):

Without posting any detail about the failures, I don't think anyone can help you debug this. You have only posted a summary.

You can skip tests with `mvn -DskipTests ...`

Comment: I have posted the whole output now. Since there is a restriction on the maximum length of the post I have omitted some stuff. Is there anything else that is required to help find the problem?

Comment: No, the real error output is in a log file generated by  the test. This snippet just says "there was some error".

Comment: Here is the test report and output for one of the failing tests. Does it help? Should I put reports for the other tests too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810191/mahout-installation-failing-pfpgrowthtest . Thanks

Comment: (It's useful to post the resolution for others)

Comment: I installed everything again and I think I used another java this time.